# Can i capture the centralized logs for all user in Apex sales force environment

Tags: salesforce

I can capture logs in developer console or eclipse id.
How can I capture all the user and system level logs( like trigger or scheduler ) once I deployed the Apex application in sales force.

Answer (score 0):

In setup -> Monitoring -> Debug Logs add the user you want to monitor.
Just note if you deployed a Managed Package most of the logs would not be available.